# Average radius of city size?

Tags: google-maps, distance, spatial-statistics, area, google-maps-api

Do any geographers on here have an estimate of the mean and median city radius sizes? I'm trying to optimize some Google Places API queries [[e.g.](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete)] and this information would be helpful for that purpose.

Comment: it turns out one can fetch the coordinates of a square convex hull drawn around a city from the Google Places API, so one can get a good radius estimate from that feature, but I'll leave this open as I am curious if there are public statistics on this question

Answer (score 2):

In [The influence of urban form on spatial costs](https://www.cairn.info/revue-recherches-economiques-de-louvain-2011-2-page-23.htm?contenu=article), the radius used is the radius of the circle that has the same surface area than the analyzed area (accesible area of a service from an urban area with its surrounding area of non-urban land, to simulate monocentric cities).

In any case, using that kind of *"authalic circle"* seems to me a good option.

Comment: Amen, I like that measure, thanks for the reference!